# Ubuntu 14... freezes after kernel selection, stops on a specific line in recovery mode

Tags: freeze

I have Linux 14 something running on a Macbook and have about 10 kernels to choose from, from 4.2.0-42 down to 3.13 something. All of them were working, but after I repeatedly restarted my computer to try all the kernels about 20 times, the booting process stops on the black/purple screen before showing the Ubuntu sign with the 5 white/orange dots. This happens with all the kernel versions (that i have tried), even if i dont press anything at all and let it boot by itself. Booting up to the grub works fine. In recovery mode it starts booting, but stops a second in on the line:

```
[ 0.675215] ehci-pci 0000:00:04.1: irq 22, io mem 0xd338920
```

after more than 10 minutes nothing happens 
(This line is the same for all versions, but the number at the beginning varies)

I didn't do anything specific before the issue started, I was just trying to select a kernel version which allowed my wacom tablet to work.

Extra info: when it was still working, after boot if I rebooted or turned the computer off and back on, it did not want to enter grub or boot up. I had to press the power button to restart the computer a second time.

Thanks for all the help, I've no idea what is wrong with it my only guess is that I have restarted the computer too many times???

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

## 1 easy solution

Just unplug (from electricity) your computer for 10 seconds,
plug again and it might work! (yes it does)

## 2 if it doesn't work (edit grub)

The solution was in Grub
go to: Advanced Options
There I went to the 'Recovery mode option'
prees 'e' to go to the editor.
edit the line

```
linux /vmlinuz-3.0.2..... nomodeset acpi=off
```

press F10 to boot.
That way it did boot, but it didn't recognize the keyboard.

This confirmed with an 'acpi' issue.

The next thing I did is a restarted the computer
and went testing the different acpi options
in [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI#Debugging_procedure).

The one that did it for me was

```
nolapic
```

F10 once again and then my keyboard responded
from there I ran 'fsck'.
and start again.